# For service workers, is it possible to use regular expressions in the serviceWorker.register 'scope' field?

Tags: service-worker

I have a serviceWorker hosted at the root '/' which serves one web application. There is another application being served at '/otherapp'. The issue I'm having is that the serviceWorker is intercepting the traffic that would be going to '/otherapp'. I know that the 'scope' parameter in serviceWorker.register defaults to './', but I am looking for a way to tell the serviceWorker to allow any requests to '/otherapp' to be ignored, and catch everything else. The only thing I can think of is using some type of regular expression, but I don't see any docs or topics on people doing this. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure that a regular expression would help here.  This seems more a question of whether a sub-scope can be ignored, and as far as I know the answer is no.  You can ignore `FetchEvent`s coming from `/otherapp` but you'll have to do so manually.  You could use the request's referrer, or perhaps more reliably the `clientId` on the event object along with [`clients.get`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clients/get).

Answer (score 1):

you can't specify a regular expression in the service worker scope.

What you can do is apply your regex in the fetch event handler to control what gets cached, how long it gets cached, etc. This is where you get all sorts of control.

My advice is to refactor out the logic from the event handler, possibly to a class to help you manage the code and logic a bit easier.

You can create different caching strategies based on different routes based on one or more regular expressions.

Think about it this way, service workers are like a mini web server in your browser. Just as if you were designing something like node express, ASP.NET MVC or Ruby on Rails you would need to utilize a route handler to retrieve the proper response. You need to do the same thing in your service worker.